# data not displaying on form on ajax success

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying a simple task of displaying student name in a textbox based on StudentId entered. I am able to display the student name as an alert from jQuery - AJAX call but not in the text box, what am I missing here?

Controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult DisplayStudentName(string id)
    {
        StudentDataContext db = new StudentDataContext();
        var StudentName = (from p in db.vwStudents.Where(a => a.StudentNumber == id)
                         group p by p.StudentName into g
                         select g.Key).FirstOrDefault();

        return Json(new { Name = StudentName }); 

    }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#submitButton').click(function () {
        var link = '/StudentForm/DisplayStudentName';        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: link,
            data: { id: $('#id').val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#StudentName").val(result.Name);
                alert(result.Name);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Failed")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Student Form
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="Data" style="text-align: left; height: 202px;">
Student Number:<input type="text" name="id" id="id"/><br />                
Student Name:<input type="text" name="StudentName" id="StudentName"/><br />              
<br />
 <div id="Div1">
  <button id="submitButton" name="submitButton" style="width:140px;">Display Short Name</button>
 </div>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Again, I am able to display Student Name in the Alert window, but not in the text box, Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **prevent** the default behavior of submit button. You can use the jQuery [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) function to do this,

```
$(function () {
    $('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();    //prevent default behaviour
        var link = '/StudentForm/DisplayStudentName';        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: link,
            data: { id: $('#id').val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {                  
                $("#StudentName").val(result.Name);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Failed")
            }
        });
    });
})
```

When `preventDefault` method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered. So in this case the form submission will not happen ( so the page wont be reloaded).

Comment: It worked! could you tell me what preventDefault() callback does?

Comment: @user793468: it prevents the default behavior( the form submit in this case). you were not able to see in the textbox because the page was reloading (hence clearing the textbox value) due to the form submission.